# Zend_Form_Element::clearValidators() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form. Why is the `clearValidators()` line not working in this example?

```
$element = $form->getElement('field1');
$element->clearValidators();
var_dump($element->isValid(''));
print_r($element->getErrors());
```

Outputs

```
bool(false)
Array
(
    [0] => isEmpty
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the possibility of having an allowEmpty flag on an element.  Try:

```
$element = $form->getElement('field1');
$element->clearValidators();
$element->setAllowEmpty(true);
var_dump($element->isValid(''));
print_r($element->getErrors());
```

Comment: I didn't know about `$element->setAllowEmpty(true)`. But `$element->setIsRequired(false)` did work.